# KAFKA partition data achieving data dailywise

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible in Kafka to archive data daily-wise to some directory?
Also let me know is it possible to create a partition on a daily base.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kafka Connect with the `DailyPartitioner` class in Confluent's connectors to backup topic data to HDFS or S3

There's also FileSink connectors for local disk out of the box with Kafka, but you might need to implement the partitioner yourself